# Reversal of Blacklisting

Tags: word-choice

I'm curious to know if anyone know a word that describes the process of removing an item from a blacklist.

For example if we replaced the word "blacklist" with "ban" the one would "Ban an object" and later "Lift the ban".

What would be the word / phrase used to describe the same process with regards to blacklisting?

Whitelist is unsuitable because it carries the connotation of everything being banned by default and only certain items are allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You found it already. It is to ***remove from a blacklist***.

For example, below articles are from *ehow.com*:

- [How to Remove From a Blacklist](http://www.ehow.com/how_7551060_remove-blacklist.html)
- [How to Remove From Spam Blacklist](http://www.ehow.com/how_6599978_remove-spam-blacklist.html)

I see the usage of *delisting* also but it is less common.

Answer (score 2):

Consider *deblacklist* or *de-blacklist*.

A google search showed a number of different types of this use, including in a "publication" (recognizing that what is and isn't a publication has become blurred, or more blurred, in the digital age), though it's still fairly uncommon and probably won't be found in a dictionary.

> [How do you de-blacklist a WF ?](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/6758626310)
>   Question asked on a gaming site. (*WF* means *whisper-friendly*, open to receiving private messages.)
>
> [India Clears Denel Of Corruption Charges, De-Blacklists Company](http://www.defenseworld.net/news/10923/India_Clears_Denel_Of_Corruption_Charges__De_Blacklists_Company#.VMsGhJ9m7qA)
>   The term is repeated in the text of the article. From a "defence and aerospace news portal".

I think most readers, especially in a technical or relatively informal text, would understand instantly without giving it a second thought.

As suggested in [sojourner](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/107561/sojourner)'s answer on the current page, *unblacklist* is also currently used. I personally prefer de- because it seems to distinguish a removal over something that has never been blacklisted. (It also allows us to use the wonderful *undeblacklist* as soon at the soonest opportunity.)

To be more conservative, stay with "remove from a/the blacklist".

Answer (score 1):

the phrase is: unblacklist.
I found it is an acceptable usage:

https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=unblacklist

Comment: Maybe our answers should be combined? You can add my answer to yours, if you'd like. Or I'd be happy to add yours to mine. I would use de- because unlisted has a commonly held meaning that differs from what I think de-listed conveys. But I think both are clear and useful.

Comment: go ahead brother add mine to yours.

Comment: Hmmm.... I'm not sure if that's the best thing to do or not. I'll ask about this on the meta site. For now, I'll just +1 yours.

Answer (score -1):

The common term for *removing* an item from a blacklist is to ***[unblock](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/unblock)***.

> <sup>2</sup> Restore access to or the use of (email or a website or cellular phone)
> (ODO)

An example from Facebook's [help page](https://www.facebook.com/help/115916435160582):

> **How do I unblock someone?**
>
> To unblock someone:
>
> 1. Click [icon] in the upper-right corner of your homepage and select How do I stop someone from bothering me?
> 2. Click View All Blocked Users.
> 3. Click **Unblock** next to the name of the person you want to **unblock**.

Answer (score -1):

There are several "single-word answers" that meet this exact description:

The most technically correct is [decatagorize](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/decategorize)

This perfectly fits technical and non-technical usages of blacklist. To blacklist something is to formally categorize it as forbidden. However this is not a phrase with a lot of 'flow' to it, and despite universal accuracy, you're only going to hear it used in technical contexts.

Decatagorize can be used in an absolute sense "That's no longer a threat, so we're going to decatgorize it (entirely)." or in a specific sense "we're going to decatagorize that from the blacklist (and leave it unchanged in other existing categories".

A more conversational word is delist. It still assumes the parties understand what list is being discussed, but it's a bit more known outside of technical fields because things like stocks and other regulated products are subject to being '[delisted](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/delisting.asp)'.

Another technical concept is the [greylist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blacklist_%28computing%29):

> A greylist contains items that are temporarily blocked (or temporarily
>   allowed) until an additional step is performed.

In many situations that have a White list on one end and a Black list on the other, there may be an implicit or explicit greylist whose items are subject to examination when encountered.